# How to flush CocoaAsyncSocket?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, cocoaasyncsocket

Is there a way to flush the internal buffers/queues/etc. of CocoaAsyncSocket (GCDasyncSocket)?

I want to setup the environment that when I call the **[... readDataWithTimeout ..]** method, I don't want it to read any left over garbage data from a previous connection that might have been buffered and sitting somewhere.

Or sometimes I just want to ignore a stream of data and start over, so want to ensure a clean pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked this question in the CocoaAsyncSocket Google Group and Robbie Hanson was kind enough to elaborate with [***his answer***](http://groups.google.com/group/cocoaasyncsocket/browse_thread/thread/92ccbb9eff9ae04e?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send \n or \r after you write data.
I have write a socket manager class you can check it here: [CocoaAsyncSocketManager](https://github.com/AdriatikGashi/CocoaAsyncSocketManger/blob/master/CocoaAsyncSocketManager/Managers/CCSocketManager.swift)

Sample code:

```
func sendMessage(messageString msg: String) {
    if let _data = msg.data(using: .utf8), let _carriageReturn = "\r".data(using: .utf8) {
        tcpSocket?.write(_data, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
        tcpSocket?.write(_carriageReturn, withTimeout: -1, tag: 99)
    }
}
```